# illegal document key in ArangoDB graph

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-java

I am starting in ArangoDB, through an access in a Java application. In the project, I need to create a collection of employees and a dynamic number of vertices of stockings, with connections between employees and these stockings through edges, as shown in the figure.

[image]

In the codes below I am creating only one stocking (just use a loop to create the others). The problem is how to create the edge.

I can already create the Capacity and Employee vertices. These collections must be connected through the edge Vacation, but I am not able to create the edges.

Initially, I used **Solution1**, based on [this code](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/tree/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/example/graph). With this code, the three collections are created as a vertex, but the edges are not created interconnecting the Employees and Stockings.

Adapting the code for **Solution 2**. based on the [following script](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.arangodb.entity.BaseEdgeDocument), `“Error: 1221 - illegal document key”` was generated when executing `createGraph()` (see marked line).

I ask the experts for help in identifying how to create the graph correctly.

**Solution1**

```
ArangoDB arangoUtil = new ArangoDB.Builder()
              .serializer(new ArangoJack())
              .host(ARANGODB_HOST, ARANGODB_PORT)
              .user(ARANGODB_USER)
              .password(ARANGODB_PASSWORD)
              .useProtocol(Protocol.HTTP_JSON)
              .build();

registerStockings();
//each employee has more than one vacation record per year
for(Vacation v : listVacations){
    registerEmployees(v);
    registerVacations(v);
}


private registerStockings() throws ArangoDBException{
    BaseDocument bDoc;
    for(Stocking s : list){
        bDoc = new BaseDocument();
        bDoc.setKey(s.getUorg());
        bDoc.addAttribute("nomeLotacao", s.getNome());
        bDoc.addAttribute("descricao", s.getDescricao());
        arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE)
                    .collection(“Stock”)
                        .insertDocument(bDoc);
    }
}


private void registerEmployees(Vacation v) throws ArangoDBException{
    BaseDocument bDoc = new BaseDocument();
    bDoc = new BaseDocument();
    bDoc.setKey(v.getSiape());
    bDoc.addAttribute("nomeServidor", v.getNomeServidor());
    arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE)
        .collection("Employees")
            .insertDocument(bDoc);
}


private void registerVacations(Vacation v) throws ArangoDBException{
    BaseEdgeDocument bDoc = createEdgeValue();
    bDoc.setKey(sb.append(v.getSiape()).append("_").append(v.getDataInicio().getTime()).toString());
    bDoc.addAttribute("exercicio", v.getExercicio());
    bDoc.addAttribute("duracao", v.getDuracao());
    bDoc.addAttribute("dataInicio", v.getDataInicio());
    bDoc.addAttribute("dataFim", v.getDataFim());
    bDoc.setFrom(“Employees”);
    bDoc.setTo(“Stockings”);
    arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE)
                .graph(“MyGraph”)
                    .edgeCollection(“Vacations”)
                        .insertEdge(bDoc);
}

private static BaseEdgeDocument createEdgeValue(){
    VertexEntity v1 = arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE)
                                    .graph(“MyGraph”)
                                        .vertexCollection(“Employees”)
                                            .insertVertex(new BaseDocument(), null);
    VertexEntity v2 = arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE)
                                    .graph(“MyGraph”)
                                        .vertexCollection(“Stockings”)
                                            .insertVertex(new BaseDocument(), null);

    BaseEdgeDocument bed = new BaseEdgeDocument();
    bed.setFrom(v1.getId());
    bed.setTo(v2.getId());
    return bed;
}
```

**Solution2**

```
ArangoDB arangoUtil = new ArangoDB.Builder()
              .serializer(new ArangoJack())
              .host(ARANGODB_HOST, ARANGODB_PORT)
              .user(ARANGODB_USER)
              .password(ARANGODB_PASSWORD)
              .useProtocol(Protocol.HTTP_JSON)
              .build();

createCollections();
registerStockings();
//each employee has more than one vacation record per year
for(Vacation v : listVacations){
    registerEmployees(v);
    registerVacations(v);
}




private void createCollections() throws ArangoDBException{
    arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE).createCollection(“Employees”,
                                        new CollectionCreateOptions().type(CollectionType.DOCUMENT));
    arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE).createCollection(“Stockings”,
                                        new CollectionCreateOptions().type(CollectionType.DOCUMENT));
    arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE).createCollection(“Vacations”,
                                        new CollectionCreateOptions().type(CollectionType.EDGES));
    
    List<EdgeDefinition> listEdgeDef = new ArrayList<EdgeDefinition>();
    EdgeDefinition edgeDef = new EdgeDefinition();
    edgeDef.collection(“Vacations”);
    edgeDef.from(“Employees”);
    edgeDef.to(“Stockings”);
    listEdgeDef.add(edgeDef);
    arangoUtil.db(ARANGODB_DATABASE).createGraph(“MyGraph”, listEdgeDef, null);      **** error ****
}
```

Comment: You can find here examples about creating a graph from the java driver: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/tree/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/example/graph

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @rashtao. I accessed this link and my Solution1 was based on this code (I will even change the post to make reference to it), but as I did not achieve my goal, I searched for new sources. I will do further tests using your suggestion. Thank you again.

Comment: @rashtao, as I said, I used your link as a reference for Solution2 (I said it wrong in the comment above). I reviewed your code and saw that it looks very similar, and my error remains in the same place, when executing the line with `createGraph()`. Realize that the error occurs BEFORE the insertion of elements, why would it be an error related to the illegal key?